# java orm/data access object - interface for deleting a record

Tags: java, orm, interface, dao

I've got a following Java interface that is used as a DAO for `Category` entities:

```
public interface CategoryDao extends Dao {

    public void save(Category category);

    public void update(Category category);

    public void delete(Category category);

    public List<Category> findAllByType(String type);
}
```

Above is what I've designed, but I'm afraid the `delete` method isn't very good. This is because if I wanted to delete a record, I would have to fetch it from the database first - and this is excessive. SQL allows to delete a record just by passing the primary key (id in this case). Would it be better if I provided a `deleteById(int)` method?

Could anyone suggest the right approach (could be the simplest/fastest possible) on how to provide a DAO delete method for ORM entities?

Comment: @JBNizet it's hibernate, if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one, or the other, or both. In any case, Hibernate needs an instance of the entity to delete it using `session.delete()`. You can get such an instance without loading the entity from the database using `session.load()`, which returns a lazy-loaded proxy.

So the deleteById() method would be implemented using

```
Category c = (Category) session.load(Category.class, id);
delete(c);
```